# Google Chrome loads new tab extension zoomed out

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, svelte

I am trying to build a Chrome new tab extension. Now, when I load the built files in Chrome as an extension, the view looks zoomed out. Everything is the same, just zoomed out. I have no clue why this happens. I am using Svelte if that's gonna help.

Here are the visuals.

The usual and expected look.

[image: the app]

The way it looks in Chrome.
[image: the extension]

Comment: Can you try running it on an Incognito Window? That way, we can be sure that no other Chrome Extensions are running.

Comment: seems like you need an HTML meta tag with initial-scale and viewport attributes

Comment: @kvncnls it says that "Incognito windows are treated specially. New Tab pages cannot be overridden in incognito windows" [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override)

Comment: @frozen I've got these `<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1>`

Comment: Maybe you've accidentally zoomed out another page in your extension? Open it and see if there's a magnifier icon in the address bar. If it helps, there's a bug in Chrome: it doesn't show the magnifier icon on newtab replacement page.

Comment: @wOxxOm I do not think so, because when I zoom in or out, the magnifier icon shows up, and the percentage is right. So, nothing about that. Also, I just created a simple HTML with h1 tag and some text without applying a font. But when I loaded the extension, it had a different font and different size.

Comment: Did you customize/change fonts in Chrome's settings?

Comment: No, I did not customize any Chrome settings, actually.

Comment: The icon seems to be the same size so how have you define your `font-size` in css? Can you please share more details about your `css`?

Comment: @johannchopin I have just set a fixed font-size for that icon. I have not changed any font-size besides that.

Comment: @MensurQulami Ok but how? Using `px` or `em`?

Comment: It is pixel, what do you think might be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this happens because Chrome injects a default `font-family` and `font-size` to the `body` of the HTML. So, if you put your own configuration for the font in the `body`, then it will pick up that.